# Edited my style but screwed up mobile view

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, woocommerce, woothemes

I edited the style for my new theme but can't seem to find the issue with mobile view to fix it. any help would greatly be appreciated. Here is what I worked out on Mobile view so far. Also, is there a way to inspect element on mobile using mac? Thanks.

```
/* ************************************************************** */
/* Mobile 0px - 720px */
/* ************************************************************** */
@media only screen and (max-width: 719px) {

/* Grid */
.grid_1,.grid_2,.grid_3,.grid_4,.grid_5,.grid_6,.grid_7,.grid_8,.grid_9,.grid_10,.grid_11,.grid_12{margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;clear:both}.alpha,.omega{margin-left:0;margin-right:0}.align_center,.align_right{text-align:left}

.gbtr_tools_info {
    display:none;
}

.mobiles_menus_wrapper {
    float:none;
    max-width:270px;
    margin:0px auto 0 auto;
    height:auto;
}

.gbtr_poduct_details_left_col {
    width:300px;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.gbtr_poduct_details_left_col {
    width:300px;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.doubleSlider-1 img {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
}

.gbtr_poduct_details_right_col {
    width:300px;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.product_navigation.mobiles .nav-back {
    display:none;
}

.gbtr_product_share ul li {
    margin:0 10px;
    width:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.gbtr_product_share ul li a {
    padding: 8px 0px 0 60px;
}

div.product .woocommerce_tabs ul.tabs, #content div.product .woocommerce_tabs ul.tabs,
div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs, #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs {
    border: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0 !important;
}

div.product .woocommerce_tabs .panel, #content div.product .woocommerce_tabs .panel,
div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel, #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-left: 0;
}

div.product .woocommerce_tabs ul.tabs li, #content div.product .woocommerce_tabs ul.tabs li,
div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li, #content div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.product_main_infos span.onsale {
    top: -20px;
    left: 220px;
}

.single_add_to_cart_button {
    width:160px;
}

.testimonial_left_content {
    width:89%;
    padding:5%;
    float:none;
}

.testimonial_left_author {
    width:95%;
    float:none;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.testimonial_left_author img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    max-width:50px !important;
}

.testimonial_left_author h4 {
    padding-top:5px;
}

.testimonial_left_content:after, .testimonial_left_content:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.testimonial_left_content:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.testimonial_left_content:before {
    border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 16px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

.testimonial_right_content {
    width:89%;
    padding:5%;
    float:none;
}

.testimonial_right_author {
    margin-top:30px;
    width:95%;
    float:none;
}

.testimonial_right_author img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    max-width:50px !important;
}

.testimonial_right_author h4 {
    padding-top:5px;
}

.testimonial_right_content:after, .testimonial_right_content:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.testimonial_right_content:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-width: 15px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.testimonial_right_content:before {
    border-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0);
    border-top-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 16px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

.listing_products_no_sidebar {
    max-width:100% !important;
    text-align:center;
}

.listing_products_no_sidebar .filter_wrapper {
    right: 0px;
}

.listing_products_no_sidebar .category_header {
    padding: 0;
}

#mc_signup_submit {
    width:100px !important;
}

.widget input[type="text"], .widget input[type="password"] {
    width: 84% !important;
}

.from_the_portfolio {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.from_the_portfolio_item  { 
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 20px 0 !important;
}

ul.products {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.product_item {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0px 30px 0px !important;
}

/*.featured_products_slider .gbtr_items_slider {
    height: 500px;
}

.featured_products_slider_item  {   
    width:220px;
}*/

.style_1 .products_slider_item  {   
    width:320px;
}

.style_1 .products_slider_images {
    width:300px;
}

.gbtr_left_column_my_account {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right: 0;
}

.gbtr_left_column_my_account:after, .gbtr_left_column_my_account:before {
    content:normal;
}

.gbtr_left_column_my_account ul.menu_my_account {
    padding: 0 0 30px 0 !important;
}

.entry-title {
    text-align:center;
}

.gbtr_logo {
    padding:0 0;
    display:block;
    margin:20px auto -20px auto;
    width:270px;
    position:relative;
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.listing_products_no_sidebar .filter_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:10px 0 0 0 !important;
    text-align:center;
}

footer.entry-meta .comments-link {
    display:none;
}

.edit-link {
    display:none;
}

.gbtr_logo {
    left:0px;
}

.gbtr_items_slider.from_the_blog
{
    /* required */
    height: 400px;
}

.from_the_blog_item  {  
    width:250px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;
    list-style:none !important;
}

.from_the_blog_item:last-child  {   
    width:200px;
}

.from_the_blog_content {
    width:190px;
}

.from_the_blog_img {
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}

}

/* ************************************************************** */
/* Mobile 480px - 720px */
/* ************************************************************** */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 719px) {

.gbtr_poduct_details_left_col {
    width:460px;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.gbtr_poduct_details_right_col {
    width:460px;
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.product_main_infos span.onsale {
    top: -20px;
    left: 380px;
}

.doubleSlider-1 img {
    width:480px;
    height:auto;
}

.gbtr_product_share ul li {
    margin:0 20px;
}

.listing_products {
    width:473px;
    padding-left:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

.from_the_portfolio_item  { 
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 20px 20px 0 !important;
}

.product_item {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 50px 30px 0px !important;
}

}

/* ************************************************************** */
/* Mobile 0px - 479px */
/* ************************************************************** */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {


}

/*****************************************************************************************************/
/******************************************* /Media Queries ******************************************/
/*****************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: "screwed up mobile view" What was working before that isn't now? You'll need to be a little more specific

Comment: The layout boxes are kinda messy in mobile view. For instance the website only show half and the other half show only background. The product page is cut off in half. Thanks for your help

Comment: If I only know how to inspect mobile view on my mac that would be great I can figure it out on my own